# How to load a web page in a WebView by clicking on a button in other stage?

Tags: webview, javafx

i'm working on a browser with JavaFX i want to load a web page in `FXMLFile1` contains `WebView` just by clicking on `Button` in `FXMLFile2` to show the page in `FXMLFile1` i tried this code :

```
@FXML
 public void tabfirst (ActionEvent ee) throws IOException { //for the FXMLFile2's button text.


            Socket socket = new Socket();
    try {

        //open cursor
        panoo.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        que.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        bbb.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

        //do work

        WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine(); //this web view is in FXMLFile1
        myWebEngine.load("https://www.google.com");



    }
   catch (IOException e){
       final  Stage stg = new Stage();           
        stg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stg.initOwner(stg);
        stg.setTitle("Cannot connect to the internet /n Please Verify your connection internet");
        labelno.setText("Cannot connect to the internet...");

       //set cursor
         ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

   } finally{
       try{ socket.close(); } catch (Exception e){ }
       }

}
```

note this class `tabfirst` is in the `Button` in the `FXMLFile2` and the two FXMLfiles are in the same controller.
so please can any body show me what's wrong with my code and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code unfortunately doesn't illustrate your problem clearly enough. For instance you mention stage1 and stage2 but those variables don't exist !?

Comment: @Jurgen i've edited my post to clear the problem enough.

Comment: Where or how does web1 get set ?

Comment: Sorry @Jurgen i don't understood you!

Comment: You say that `tabfirst` is for the button in FXMLFile2 and that `WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine(); //this web view is in FXMLFile1`. So how are you setting the web1 variable to hold the web view that is in FXMLFile1 ?

Comment: @Jurgen i did this: FXML WebView web1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are setting web1. I think that because the 2 FXML files are using the same controller (Edit: my bad, I misread/misunderstood) you are expecting that they are automatically sharing variables, which they do not !

When the FXMLLoader loads an FXML file it creates a **new** instance of the controller every time. So the controller instance from FXMLfile1 doesn't know about the controller instance of FXMLfile2 or any of its variables.

There are about 5 different ways of sharing information between controllers:

1. The simplest is just using getters and setters between the two.
2. Also fairly simple is to bind properties between the two.
3. You could setup listeners and then notify them of changes.
4. Use a messaging bus.
5. Use injection.

Which one you use depends on various factors and requires more information as to what you are trying to accomplish ?

A basic outline of options 1 & 2 would look something like this:

```
FXMLLoader  fxml1 = .....
fxml1.load();
ctrl1 = fxml1.getController();

FXMLLoader  fxml2 = .....
fxml2.load();
ctrl2 = fxml2.getController();

ctrl2.set????( ctrl1.get????() );  // get something from the one and set it in the other
// if the value in ctrl1 changes it does not necessarily change in ctrl2

ctrl2.property????().bind( ctrl1.property???? );  // ctrl2 binds to a property in ctrl1
// if the value of the ctrl1 property changes it WILL also change in ctrl2
```

Comment: a great thanks for you but would you mind explain the first suggestion more by giving me expamles? and thanks very much :)

Comment: Added basic outline for options 1 and 2.

Comment: It'll be something like `new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource( "name_of_your_fxml_file.fxml" ) );`

Comment: sorry! can you explain more in the getters and the stters using "Button" WebView" and thank you in advance!