# How to click on a button in fxml2 to load a web page in fxml1 in JavaFX?

Tags: button, webview, javafx

i've tried to make a browser with JavaFX i want to load a web page which is in FXMLFile1 contains WebView and in the FXMLfile2 there's a button that button loads a web page in WebView which is in FXMLFile1 i write this code but unfortunately didn't work :

```
    @FXML
 public void tabfirst (ActionEvent ee) throws IOException { 


    try {

        FXMLLoader vve = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml"));
        Button b1 = tab1b = vve.getController();
         FXMLLoader vvve = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("WorkSpace.fxml"));          
         WebView wv = web1 = vvve.getController();

        WebEngine myWebEngine = wv.getEngine();
        myWebEngine.load("https://www.google.com");
    }
   catch (IOException e){


   } 

}
```

note this class tabfirst is in the Button in the FXMLFile2 that open the webpage in the WebView and the two FXMLfiles are using the same controller. Please answer me and thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load a web page in a WebView by clicking on a button in other stage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349951/how-to-load-a-web-page-in-a-webview-by-clicking-on-a-button-in-other-stage)

Comment: You have asked this question before and you aren't providing any additional information here.

Comment: The two FXML files are not using the same controller. You don't set a controller (or a controller factory), so by default each `FXMLLoader` will create a different controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your Choose controller could have something like this:

```
public class Choose
{
    @FXML private TextField  addressField;

    /** for Button in FXML onAction="#useAddress" */
    @FXML private void useAddress()
    {
        addressProp.set( addressField.getText() );
    }

    private final StringProperty  addressProp = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty addressProperty()
    {
        return  addressProp;
    }
}
```

And your WorkSpace controller could have:

```
public class WorkSpace
{
    @FXML private WebView  web;

    public void setAddress( String address )
    {
        web.getEngine().load( address );
    }
}
```

Then in the controller that loads the two FXML files you'll have something like:

```
    FXMLLoader  workFxml = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource("WorkSpace.fxml") );
    Node  workView = workFxml.load(); // You must call load BEFORE getController !
    WorkSpace  workCtrl = workFxml.getController();

    FXMLLoader  chooseFxml = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml") );
    Node  chooseView = chooseFxml.load();
    Choose  chooseCtrl = chooseFxml.getController();

    chooseCtrl.addressProperty().addListener
    ( 
        (ov, old, newAddress) -> workCtrl.setAddress( newAddress ) 
    );
```

Alternatively if you are loading the two FXML files from inside a parent FXML with for eg: `<fx:include fx:id="work" source="WorkSpace.fxml"/>` you'll use:

```
@FXML private WorkSpace  workController; // Must end with Controller !
@FXML private Choose  chooseController;

@FXML private void initialize()
{
    chooseController.addressProperty().addListener
    (
        (ov, old, newAddress) -> workController.setAddress( newAddress ) 
    );
}
```